# How can I make template.Execute() to write to a file rather than to response.Writer?

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a below code to parse the template file and write the parsed html to ResponseWriter:-

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("view.html")
    t.Execute(w, "Hello World!")
}

func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "127.0.0.1:8080",
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/view", handler)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

and the template file "template.html" is as:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>First Program</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ . }}
</body>
</html>
```

Now, Instead of writing parsed/executed file to ResponseWriter, I would like to write those contents to html file say "parsed.html". How can I achieve it. I'm new to Go, so having hard time getting the idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles("view.html")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Create the file
f, err := os.Create("parsed.html")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Execute the template to the file.
err = t.Execute(f, "Hello World!")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Close the file when done.
f.Close()
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XL8GHtnX2MS)

Key Point: An *os.File and an http.ResponseWriter both satisfy the io.Writer interface used in the first argument to Execute.